# Using brass to chrome plated

Tags: plumbing

I had to use a brass threaded street 90 male and female  on chrome plated male nipple on commercial facet. It's trying to seep with Teflon tape any suggestions

Comment: Did you try tightening it more and/or disassembling and adding an additional wrap or two of teflon? One or both of these should fix it unless you have cracked the street ell or nipple. I would probably get bigger pipe wrenches and try to crank it as a first effort, with the understanding that brass fittings will crack if overtightened.

Comment: Yea I did heavier wrap. I'm afraid of breaking the commercial facet

Answer (score -1):

Disassemble the fitting and try RTV silicone from an auto parts store. Allow the joint to set up overnight if possible. Brass fittings are hard to seal, and do not tighten too much. Brass is soft and will stretch. If you have tightened to where almost no thread is showing on the connection, you may have to  replace the fittings. No teflon or pipe dope, just RTV silicone.

Comment: The moron that downgraded my answer obviously has no practical experience with piping and pipe threads. I have put whole piping jobs together with RTV  silicone and not one leak. Piping for hot water, steam, fuel oil, and natural l gas. If you only knew how to get things fixed and to get piping not to leak, when whole buildings or schools were in need of a quick settlement to a problem. I fee;l sorry for you. So what is your fix??

Comment: Down votes are stupid unless you know you are the smartest person in the room and have done more of a particular job than of the other people giving answers. From what I have seen most people should keep their down votes and comments to themselves.